# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - create Java Web Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I've just installed aws.amazon.com/eclipse, 
but in the eclipse menu I see **New AWS Java Project**, but not **New AWS Java Web Project**

[image]